# Bootstrap v5, how to pass a variable inside a modal (without jquery)

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

it's my first question :-)
I'm trying to pass a variable into a modal window in Bootstrap v5 possibly without use of jquery (v5 doesn't use it anymore).

I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMailButton">Send an Email</button>
```

This button fires a function "sendMailClicked"

```
document.getElementById("sendMailButton").addEventListener("click", sendMailClicked);
```

and this is the function

```
function sendMailClicked() {
   var theValue = document.getElementById('inputid').value;  
   var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('emailModal'), { backdrop: 'static' })
   myModal.show();
}
```

inside sendMailClicked the variable "theValue" is defined and its value is correct.
I want to pass this variable inside a modal window whose content should be like this: your value is *theValue*

```
<div class="modal fade" id="emailModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Do you want to send an email?</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Your value is <?= theValue ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yesSendMail" value="<?= theValue ?>">Ok invia</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I suppose being the modal window preloaded in HTML is the reason why *theValue* is undefined. Is there a way to pass theValue value to the modal window? The ideal solution would be doing it without jquery (not included in Bootstrap v5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple methods but I'm guessing the best would be to target the child in your modal inside you `sendMailClicked` function, and then set the inner html to whatever you want.

```js
function sendMailClicked() {
   var theValue = document.getElementById('inputid').value;  
   var modalContainer = document.getElementById('emailModal')
   var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalContainer, { backdrop: 'static' })
   
   modalContainer.querySelector(".modal-body").innerHTML = "Your value is: " + theValue;
   
   myModal.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. But it doesn't work. It says "Uncaught TypeError: myModal.querySelector is not a function"...

Comment: Terribly sorry, forgot that bootstrap.Modal was not an html element, but this edited solution should do the trick.

Comment: Do you know if this method can be used to pass URL parameters (like page.htm?id=1234) to the Modal? I can not seem to figure out how best to do that.